# Set position for player from variable in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Me need set random position in Start() for player as minecraft.

Player already have the script, but position don't change of default.

Error in 24 and 25 string.

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomRespawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Игрок")] // player
    public GameObject Player;

    [Header("Объявление координат")] // have position
    public int positionX;
    public int positionZ;

    [Header("Рандомные координаты")] // random position
    public int randomPosX;
    public int randomPosZ;

    private void Start()
    {
        System.Random randomPos = new System.Random();
        Vector3 positions = transform.position;

        positionX = randomPos.Next(1, 50);
        positionZ = randomPos.Next(1, 50);

        gameObject.positions.x = positionX;
        gameObject.positions.z = positionZ;
    }
}
```

I have error: (25,20): error CS1061: 'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'positions' and no accessible extension method 'positions' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?), now =(

Comment: Tank you! This is worked!

Answer (score 0):

To change the position of the attached player gameobject, you need to change this:

```cs
gameObject.positions.x = positionX;
gameObject.positions.z = positionZ;
```

To this:

```cs
Player.transform.position = new Vector3(positionX, positionZ, Player.transform.position.z);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the `position` properties from `GameObject`, you need to get the `position` from `Transform` properties.

And you can't directly set the value of `position.x` directly from a `float` value. You must create a new `Vector3` variable and set the value first. And then you can apply that variable value to your `transform.position`.